# duvida sobre property "loading" do ng-select

Tags: angular

Galera, preciso de uma ajuda!

Alguém poderia me explicar para que serve e como funciona a property "loading" do ng-select?

Comment: E uma flag que vc pode setar indicando que os items do select estão sendo carregados.

Comment: Valeu @EduardoVargas